# Bootstrap row hiding behind another one on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm very new to ASP.NET, and I'm currently using ASP.NET Core 2.0, so my issue could come from this, just letting you know.

So, what I'm trying to do is quite simple, display a row including 2 `col-md-6`, and another row under this one including a `col-md-12`.

This works perfectly on "normal" laptop screen, but when I reduce screen size to test responsiveness, the second row displays behind the first one, and in its center.

Laptop screen:

[image: Laptop screen]

Small screen:

[image: Small screen]

CSS here :

```
body {
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Wrapping element */
/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Custom changes */
body {background-color:grey;}

.form {
background-color: green;
height: 66vh;
}

.form form {
height: 100%;
}

#inputs {
height: 90%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.col-md-6 {
padding-top: 2%;
padding-bottom: 3%;
text-align: center;
background-color:orange;
height: 100%;
}

.textbox {
width: 66%;
height: 90%;
background-color: red;
resize: none;
}

#submit {
text-align: center;
background-color: pink;
height: 48px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.errors {
background-color: aqua;
}
```

And HTML:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

@{
string message = "";
string phones = "";
int error_nb = 0;
int error_line = 0;

if (Request.Method == "POST")
{
    message = Request.Form["message"];
    phones = Request.Form["phones"];
    }
}



<div class="form">
<form method="post">
    <div class="row" id="inputs">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Message:<br />
            <textarea type="text" name="message" class="textbox">@message</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Phones:<br />
            <textarea type="text" name="phones" class="textbox">@phones</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="submit">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="errors">
<textarea>@error_nb error(s) detected at line @error_line !</textarea>
</div>
```

Any idea to solve this ?
Thanks !

EDIT: Here is the _Layout.cshtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication6</title>

<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>

<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
    </script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no need to overright `width/margin` property on `.row` css. Also add clearfix class on row div

Comment: @SuperUser Thanks for this quick answer ! Why shouldn't I set margin & width to 0? Anyway, I did it, but my main problem remains

Comment: Is it inside a container?

Comment: @Salketer Well no, I didn't have any container. Just tried to set the class to the div containing the rows, but didn't change anything
Thanks anyway

Comment: It's a good idea to always have the grid inside a container or container-fluid... From bootstrap doc, first bullet on how to make it work "Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding."

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that at lower screen resolution, you have no set column... You should always define at least a col-xs-* here, I added col-xs-12 and it works.

```css
CSS here: body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


/* Wrapping element */


/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */

.body-content {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}


/* Custom changes */

body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.form {
  background-color: green;
  height: 66vh;
}

.form form {
  height: 100%;
}

#inputs {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.col-md-6 {
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}

.textbox {
  width: 66%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  resize: none;
}

#submit {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.errors {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form container">
  <form method="post">
    <div class="row" id="inputs">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        Message:<br />
        <textarea type="text" name="message" class="textbox">@message</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        Phones:<br />
        <textarea type="text" name="phones" class="textbox">@phones</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="submit">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="errors">
  <textarea>@error_nb error(s) detected at line @error_line !</textarea>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this is not documented correctly in the docs, but having columns without a XS value will have unpredictable results. Note that in your case, the CSS rule `float:left` was missing, since only col-xs-* apply it.

Comment: Mh, I tried both of your answers, and they didn't work for me. I really don't understand here

Comment: Well, my code snippet works, and it uses your CSS and HTML... Maybe there is more code to your page that interferes with it? And I only gave one answer?

Comment: I meant your answer and WeBer's
I'm going to check if there is any additionnal code

Comment: I Edited to add the _Layout file, but I don't think it can come from it. There isn't any other code that could interfere with the one I showed

Edit: I managed to fix it with WeBer's code and yours together ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It's working perfectly when am using `row-fluid` in you grid, its suggested to use `row-fluid` for better responsive cases.

[Ref link.](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)

and for the responsive issues, I have added this code for you -

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #inputs {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


/* Wrapping element */


/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */

.body-content {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}


/* Custom changes */

body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.form {
  background-color: green;
  height: 66vh;
}

.form form {
  height: 100%;
}

#inputs {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.col-md-6 {
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}

.textbox {
  width: 66%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  resize: none;
}

#submit {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.errors {
  background-color: aqua;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #inputs {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form">
  <form method="post">
    <div class="row-fluid" id="inputs">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        Message:<br />
        <textarea type="text" name="message" class="textbox">@message</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        Phones:<br />
        <textarea type="text" name="phones" class="textbox">@phones</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid" id="submit">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, didn't work at first on my side, but after a few edits, it works like a charm !